# JAXB unmarshal choose root name at runtime

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have several xml files with alternative root elements :

```
<ulti86>, 
<ulti75>, 
<ulti99>....
```

Otherwise,the xml structure is the same.

I want to unmarshal these files in the same pojo.

I saw is possible to change the name of an element in marshalling opération at runtime with

```
JAXBElement and Qname (like : JAXBElement<Customer> jaxbElement = 
new JAXBElement<Customer>(new QName(null, "customer"), Customer.class, customer);)
```

is it possible to indicate the name of the root element at runtime in unmarshalling ?

Ulti class :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Ulti {
....
}
```

unmarshal method :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Ulti.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
File xmlFile = new File(getFullFileName());
Ulti icc = (Ulti) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the `unmarshal` methods on `Unmarshaller` that take a `Class` parameter to get the behaviour you are looking for. By telling JAXB what type of `Class` you are unmarshalling it doesn't need to figure one out itself by the root element.

```
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(getFullFileName());
JAXBElement<Ulti> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource, Ulti.class);
Ulti icc = jaxbElement.getValue();
```

**Note:**

The advantage of using `Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Source, Class)` over `JAXB.unmarshal(File, Class)` is the performance benefit of processing the metadata only once by creating a `JAXBContext` that can be reused.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`JAXB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) class the name of the root element should be irrelevant, you can change it and still unmarshal will succeed.

Example input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<point>
    <x>1</x>
    <y>2</y>
</point>
```

Unmarshaling code:

```
Point p = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("p.xml"), Point.class);
System.out.println(p); // Output: java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2]
```

Now if you change the root element to for example `"<p2oint>"` and run it again, you get the same result without any errors.

Comment: I try but i have this exception : `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ulti86"). Expected elements are <{}ulti>`

Comment: @gVibrac Note that what I wrote applies to using the [`JAXB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) class. If you unmarshal in other ways, that might not be the case.

Comment: @icza `Unmarshaller` also has such method (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class)), not just `JAXB`.